# Wordpress XML-RPC publishing in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, wordpress, xml-rpc

So I'm trying to write a desktop app to publish posts to a Wordpress blog, and I found [Reuben Stanton's](http://www.absentdesign.com) Wordpress XML-RPC library (for some reason, his site isn't responding, so [here's the code on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/julapy/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fflash%2FWorpress_XML-RPC))

Now everything works well, but when I get to publishing posts, something weird happens.

Here's my code:

```
private function publish():void {
    var sel:CuratorBlog=blogSelect.selectedItem;
    publisher=new WPService(sel.url, sel.login, sel.password);
    publisher.addEventListener(WPServiceEvent.NEW_POST, postAdded);

    var p:Post=new Post();
    p.dateCreated=publishDate.selectedDate;
    p.title=txtTitle.text;
    p.mt_keywords=txtTags.text;
    p.mt_allow_comments=1;
    p.mt_allow_pings=1;
    p.description=htmlText; //This is obtained from a richText control. And yes, I have tested that it is being assigned properly

    publisher.posts.newPost(p, true);

    btnPublish.enabled=false;
    cursorManager.setBusyCursor();
}

private function postAdded(e:WPServiceEvent):void {
    var postId:String=(e.data as String);
    Alert.show(blogSelect.selectedItem.url + "?p=" + postId);
    publisher.removeEventListener(WPServiceEvent.NEW_POST, postAdded);
    cursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
    btnPublish.enabled=true;
}
```

The issue is that the post is created, but without the content.

I am able to see the tags and title in the browser when I open the blog, but it has no content. any idea why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow!! I am turning into a self-answerer (for lack of a better term) :P

Turns out something was reading the content and doing a sort of `htmlUnescape` on it.

So, I did a `htmlEscape` before I posted it, and it worked!!

A class for Html escaping and unescaping can be found from http://thingsthatwork.net/index.php/2008/06/26/html-entities-and-actionscript/